# ag-Grid: agRichSelectCellEditor not found

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I am getting below warning when using `agRichSelectCellEditor` from `ag-grid-enterprise`-

> ag-Grid: Looking for component [agRichSelectCellEditor] but it wasn't
>   found

Below import statement fixes this problem -

```
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
```

Now I have below questions -

1. `agSelectCellEditor` is present in non-enterprise package and it works fine without any import. Is the enterprise package not imported by default?
2. Is it possible to import only the required classes from `ag-grid-enterprise` instead of importing everything?
3. Above solution broke my existing custom cell editor which is an auto-complete using column filter ([Code for custom autocomplete cell editor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ag-grid-auto-complete)). The filtering does not work anymore.

Answer (score 8):

For those looking for an answer, 'agSelectCellEditor' can be used which is available for non-enterprise imports.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue using agRichSelectCellEditor. The format of the import statement provided in your question won't work from version 22.0 forward. Here's how I got it working. Note: this may address your #2 question above as well.

```
import {RichSelectModule} from '@ag-grid-enterprise/rich-select';
```

Then, inside my component:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './my.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my.component.scss']
})
export class MyComponent {
  public modules: Module[] = [RichSelectModule];
  . . .
}
```

At this point you can use it in your column definition:

```
{
  headerName: 'My Column',
  field: 'my_column',
  editable: true,
  cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
  cellEditorParams: {
    values: ['your', 'values', 'here'],
  },
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had been trying to get a 'agSetColumnFilter' working without importing everything from '@ag-grid-enterprise'

Answer (score 0):

In my Angular project I have a file called 'main.ts' and there I needed to add the agRichSelectCellEditor aka it's module like this. Then I could use it like described in the documentation

```
import { RichSelectModule } from '@ag-grid-enterprise/rich-select';

ModuleRegistry.registerModules([
    RichSelectModule
]);

then later in the ag-grid:
cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor',
```